# Searching for username and password along with other variables in a text file?

Tags: java, jframe, delimiter, readfile, file-search

I have a text file called **UserDetails.txt** that I am trying to read from.

**Each line of the text file is as follows:**

```
John : Doe : Seattle : jd3 : 1234

Jane : Doe : Olympia : jd4 : 5678
```

In which the last two variables are the username and password that I am trying to search for.

**My code:**

```
public class LoginFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{


private static Scanner keyboard = new 
Scanner(System.in);
String username;
String password;
String filePath = "UserDetails.txt";

public LoginFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

private void jButtonLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    username = jTextFieldUsername.getText();
    password = jTextFieldPassword.getText();
    verifyLogin(username,password,filePath);
   }                                            

public static void verifyLogin(String username, 
String password, String filepath)
{
   boolean match = false;
   String tempUserName = "";
   String tempPassword = "";
   try
   {
       keyboard = new Scanner(new 
       File(filepath));
       keyboard.useDelimiter("[:\n]");

       while(keyboard.hasNext() && !match)
       {
           tempUserName = keyboard.next();
           tempPassword = keyboard.next();

           if(tempUserName.trim().equals(username.trim()) && tempPassword.trim().equals(password.trim()))
           {
               match = true;
           }
       }
       keyboard.close();
       System.out.print(match);
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       System.out.print("Error");
   }
}
```

The problem that I am encountering is that I am unsure as to how I can separate the username and password from the user's first and last name. The use of the delimiter is only able to find these two specific values when the username and password are the only two variables in the text file(with the first and last names removed).

Comment: is it fixed format string? firstname:lastname:city:username:password , or the format can be different?

Comment: The format is fixed throughout the entire text file.

Comment: Also take sometime to read https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: so using delimiter ':' you can take the input in array and can take the corresponding value for username password or any other info

Answer (score 0):

read the entire line and then you can use

```
    String str = "John : Doe : Seattle : jd3 : 1234"; // input line that you read from file
    String[] arr = str.split(" : ");
    String username = arr[3]; // as index starts from 0;
    String password = arr[4]; // similarly you can get other values
```

to convert it in a array of String that will have the username at index 3
and password at index 4